# .NET 4.5 Membership Provider Database

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-authentication

I am using the standard ASP.NET Webform template and its membership provider. Specifically I am using only the external id services (Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Twitter).  All these worked fine, until I decided to point the database away from the default localdb to my own.

In web.config I changed the `connectionStringName` attribute in <profile>, <membership> and <roleManager> from the default `DefaultConnection` to my own connection string name.  The following tables were then automatically created in my database: `Users`, `Roles`, `Profiles` and `Memberships`.  However, it continued to use `UsersOpenAuthAccounts` and `UsersOpenAuthData` from localdb!

To find out who was using localdb, I deleted the connection string "DefaultConnection".  The access was from `OpenAuth.Login`.  The error message was `"Cannot attach the file d:\....\visual studio 2012\Projects\...\App_Data\DefaultConnection.mdf as database 'DefaultConnection'."`

I am puzzled why this is happening.  There is no DefaultConnection.mdf file in App_Data.  There is only a aspnet-XXXX-yyyyMMddhhmmss.mdf.

Bottomline is: how do I make the membership provider use the two OpenAuth tables in my own database?

Thanks.

Comment: I changed the database on the connection string "DefaultConnection" to my database and it works.  Is the connection string "DefaultConnection" hard-coded somewhere in one part of the Open Auth code?

Answer (score 3):

Looking in the OpenAuth class metadata from VS, there is a static string property called `ConnectionString`.

And using Reflector, the constructor of OpenAuth can be seen to initialize the `ConnectionString` property to "DefaultConnection".

The user can therefore change the connection string used by OpenAuth anytime by simply updating this property.